# JQuery AJAX loads form which uses AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a button that will call an AJAX function based on its ID. Here it pulls info (a html form) out of a PHP file. This is pretty much a simple form. It loads in perfectly. I have a function for this form as well in the main html file it gets loaded into. For testing purposes, I just want it to prevent being submitted and to append a test phrase below the form. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I tried just putting the form strait into the html file without loading it in via AJAX and it works, the form doesn't submit and it outputs the message.

Here is my code for when the button is clicked and it's told to add the form into a div:

```
$("#zip-search-button").click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($("#thezip").val() != "") {
                $.post("http://website.com/app/deal.php", {zip : $("#thezip").val(), radius : $("#radius").val()}, function(data){
                    if (data.length > 0) { 
                        // Here we add the form
                        $( "#results" ).html( data );
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is my code for when the form is submitted:

```
$("#buy-now1").click(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault();

                $( "#results" ).append( "Hiiiiiii, This is a test!" );
            });
```

Any idea why the form function doesn't work when loading the form in via AJAX?

All of this javascript is at the bottom of the body tag in the main html file.

Comment: Do you load the form via AJAX? or the form is part of the PHP/HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#zip-search-button").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#thezip").val() != "") {
        $.post("http://website.com/app/deal.php", {zip : $("#thezip").val(), radius : $("#radius").val()}, function(data){
            if (data.length > 0) { 
                $("#results").html(data);
                $("#buy-now1").click(function(e){ 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#results").append("Hiiiiiii, This is a test!");
                });
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check out `.on` in the jquery docs.](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Basically, since your form didn't exist when the page loaded, your event handler wasn't attached. Use .on to attach a listener to a parent element that will exist at document load and you'll be golden.

Comment: Makes sense but I don't really know how to get this working :/

Answer (score 1):

Bind your events when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#buy-now1").click(function(e){ 

                 e.preventDefault();
                 $( "#results" ).append( "Hiiiiiii, This is a test!" );
       });
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken based upon Amie's description, the buy-now1 button is a part of the form that comes through the Ajax call. This will not work because the document will be ready, but the button will not be on the page. When it does get loaded the click event will not be attached.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your submit button into just a button? No more problems with your form submitting.

```
<button type="button" onclick="yourfunction();">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Cause there are input values that I need ;)